# Spinner1 populate from array, then select second array for spinner2 based on 1st spinner selection

Tags: android, arrays, string, spinner

Okay spinner 1 uses Manu_array
     spinner 2 uses Manu 1xsd, Manu 2xrsd or 3x4rsd
     all I need for now is to be able to populate the second spinner, after selecting the a value from the Manu_array in spinner 1.

```
<!--for spinner 1-->
<string-array name="Manu_array">
<item>Manu 1xsd</item>
<item>Manu 2xrsd</item>
<item>Manu 3x4rsd</item>
</string-array>

<!--for spinner 2-->
<string-array name="Manu 1xsd">
<item>a1</item>
<item>a2</item>
<item>a3</item>
<item>a4</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Manu 2xrsd">
<item>bg 1</item>
<item>bg 2</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Manu 3x4rsd">
<item>z1</item>
<item>z2</item>
<item>zd4</item>
<item>xs5</item>
<item>fg34</item>
</string-array>
```

My java file code:

```
 final Spinner[] spinner1 = {(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1)};

  // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner     layout
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
  R.array.Manu_array, R.layout.textview);

  spinner1[0].setAdapter(adapter);
  // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner1[0].setAdapter(adapter);

 spinner1[0].setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {

            int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
            // storing string resources into Array
            Manu= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Manu_array);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected : " + Manu[index],
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
```

I can process code that will allow the spinner to populate with the array data, but I cant get the second spinner to populate based on the selection of the first spinner, surely its simple if equals value use array.

The spinner above shows the values for the Manu_array, the next spinner has to take the value selected and populate with the appropriate array values, but all I have managed to do is generate a second spinner with the array values I have manual typed in, not selected.

```
if(Manu.equals("Manu 1xsd")){spinner2  languages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Manu 1xsd_array)}else......
```

Any suggestions where I may look for examples please looked at a few on here and confused me something chronic.

Comment: populate your second spinner inside itemSelected method of first spinner

Comment: Thanks I think I have looked at examples of this but couldn't follow it, I will look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the second spinner adapter when an item from the first spinner is clicked

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        int arrayId = 0;
        switch(position) {//get array id according to selected position
            case 0:
               arrayId = R.array.Manu_1xsd;
               break;
            case 1:
               arrayId = R.array.Manu_2xrsd;
               break;
            case 2:
               arrayId = R.array.Manu_3x4rsd;
               break;
        };
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, arrayId, R.layout.textview);

        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Comment: oh right, just use `YourActivityName.this` instead if you're inside an `Activity`, or replace `this` with `getActivity()` if you are in a `Fragment`

Comment: Hi thanks, I must be doing something wrong it is saying that the spinner2 needs to be final, I set as final and then .setAdapter goes red cannot resolve method 'setAdapter(androidwidget.ArrayAdapter<java.lang.CharSequence>)'

Comment: make sure that `spinner2` is of type `Spinner`; is spinner2 initialized like this? `Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);`

Comment: Thanks for the help Dimitri, however I can seem to select the newly populated spinner 2 and do something, so how do I integrate on select of item in the newly populated spinner 2?